# Python function return dict, how to write the documentation

Tags: python

I have a function which returns a `dict`:

```py
def getCard(deckListIn) -> dict:
    thisCard = deckListIn.pop() # pop one off the top of the deck and return
    return thisCard
```

`thisCard` is a `dict` that looks like this:

```py
thisCard = {
    'rank': rank,
    'suit': suit,
    'value': thisValue + 1
}
```

How do I write the **function documentation** so when I code like below, the editor (like VScode) will show up the **hint** [rank, suit, value] when I am using dot operator?

```py
currentCard = getCard(cardDesk)
print(currentCard.rank)
```

Now it behaves like this:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need *documentation* (although [documenting](https://realpython.com/documenting-python-code/) is never a bad choice) .
I think that what you need is to transform your dict into a *class*

```py
class Card:
    def __init__(self,rank,suit,value):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

def getCard(deckListIn: list[Card]) -> Card:
    thisCard = deckListIn.pop()
    return thisCard
```

Be careful that now `deckListIn` should contains `Cards` and not dictionaries.

> Note: I wrote `list[Card]`. This will work only for Python>=3.10.
> Otherwise you should use `List[Card]` after `from typing import List`, or simply remove that type hinting.

How to create a Card from a dict

```py
my_dict = {'rank':1, 'suit':2, 'value':3}

my_card = Card(**my_dict)
```

Vice versa

```py
my_card = Card(1,2,3)

my_dict = my_card.__dict__
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly - your code editor is displaying that information from the function's docstring: https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/#multi-line-docstrings

Answer (score 0):

This access only works, if you model your Dict as a python class (it has nothing to do with the IDE). For dicts, you must use `currentCard.get('rank')` or `currentCard['rank']`.

Example with class model:

```
class Card:
    value = 0

    def __init__(self, this_value):
        self.value = this_value + 1
```

Access via `Card.value` or `c.value` if `c = Card(1)`